# Print all paths of 1s from top left to bottom right cell in a matrix

Tags: python, data-structures, dynamic-programming

> You are given a 2-D matrix with M rows and N columns.You are initially positioned at (0,0) which is the top-left cell in the array. You are allowed to move either right (R) or downwards (D). The array is filled with 1’s and 0’s. A 1 indicates that you can move through that cell, a 0 indicates that you cannot move through that cell.
> Print all possible paths from top-left cell to bottom-right cell.(i.e. (0,0)to(M-1,N-1)).
> Output can be like [[R,R,D,D], [R,D,D,R], [D,D,R,R]]

Not able to generate correct output with the code I tried below:

```py
def traverse(grid, rows, cols, i, j, result, path, element):
    if i==rows-1 and j==cols-1:
        result.append(path)
        print(result)
        path = []
        return
    if i>=rows or j>=cols or grid[i][j]==0:
        path = []
        return
    if grid[i][j] == 1 and element != 'x':
        path.append(element)
    traverse(grid, rows, cols, i, j+1, result, path, 'r')
    traverse(grid, rows, cols, i+1, j, result, path, 'd')

grid = [[1,1,1],[0,1,1],[1,1,1]]
rows = len(grid)
cols = len(grid[0])
traverse(grid, rows, cols, 0, 0, [], [], 'x')
```

Comment: Are `you` supposed to share with what you have tried, and where do you get stuck? Please post the code in Prob. description, not in comment.

Comment: Please post the code in the **question** where you can properly format it, not in comments. Comments are intended to *ask* for clarification and can be removed at any time.

Comment: Your `indentation` is off - needs to be fixed.

Comment: @DanielHao posted through mobile earlier, corrected the indentation now. Can someone please help generate the correct output

Comment: What output do you currently get?

Comment: @OneCricketeer Below is what I am getting
[['r', 'r', 'd']]
[['r', 'r', 'd', 'd', 'r'], ['r', 'r', 'd', 'd', 'r']]
[['r', 'r', 'd', 'd', 'r', 'd'], ['r', 'r', 'd', 'd', 'r', 'd'], ['r', 'r', 'd', 'd', 'r', 'd']]